# Unable to decode JSON into PHP array and display in HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, html-table

I have this json data

```
{
   "next_offset": -1,
   "records":    [
            {
         "id": "87dad127-a60e-15a3-148e-56c7675f11df",
         "name": "1A Unit",
         "suite": "1A",
         "sf": 1200,
         "unit_floor": 1,
      },
            {
         "id": "f386a7ad-d6ea-6eb1-9b8f-56cd6104c445",
         "name": "3B Unit",
         "suite": "3B",
         "sf": 450,
         "unit_floor": 3,
      },
            {
         "id": "b352dc84-8c76-6c27-daa4-56cd61e71aa2",
         "name": "3A Unit",
         "suite": "3A",
         "sf": 450,
         "unit_floor": 3,
      },
            {
         "id": "8ec4325a-1271-560e-888b-56cd6120f5de",
         "name": "2B Unit",
         "suite": "2B",
         "sf": 450,
         "unit_floor": 2,
      },
            {
         "id": "5a15fd5e-246a-be4b-fd5d-56cd619e9ee1",
         "name": "1B Unit",
         "suite": "1B",
         "sf": 450,
         "unit_floor": 1,
      },
            {
         "id": "61a55092-5683-1088-2d6c-56c99c5d4873",
         "name": "2A Unit",
         "suite": "2A",
         "sf": 3000,
         "unit_floor": 2,
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to display this data in table depending on the floor number,. Like 3rd floor units 3A, 3B and total of their area in sqft in one row, 2nd floor units 2A, 2B and their sum of area in one row and 1st floor units 1A, 1B and their area sum in one row. Please help me.

I tried this but its not giving the expected result

```
$unit_response = call($url, $oauth2_token_response->access_token, 'GET');

        $unit_json = json_decode(json_encode($unit_response),true);
    <table class="stak-plan">

                <?php foreach ($unit_json['records'] as $unit_data) { ?>

                <tr>
                    <td>Floor: 3</td>
                    <td> 
                        Suit : <?php echo $unit_data['name'] ?><br>
                        SF : <?php echo $unit_data['sf'] ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>Suite: 3B<br /> SF: 25,000</td>
                    <td>Suite: 3C<br /> SF: 25,000</td>
                    <td> 
                    </td>
                </tr>  
                <?php } ?>

                </table>
```

Here is the expected output,.
[image: Output]

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Have you tried anything? wheres the code you have tried? Do you want us to do this for you?

Comment: thanks for including your code.

Comment: Where is the json_decode declaration? We need to see where you get the data and how you pull it into the json_decode to know well what you're doing.

Comment: Your JSON is not formatted properly. There are extra commas. This will prevent it from being decoded properly. Copy and paste your JSON here: http://pro.jsonlint.com/ to check it.

Comment: Have you tried my answer? I would say its the most accurate answer with the shortest code needed. Let me know if it works, im just curious.

Comment: It does worked @CodeGidie,. Thank you so much,. I also had one more REST call to be made after making Call to get Unit info,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
<style>
    td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

JSON (some extra commas has been removed):

```
$json = '{
    "next_offset": -1,
    "records":    [
             {
          "id": "87dad127-a60e-15a3-148e-56c7675f11df",
          "name": "1A Unit",
          "suite": "1A",
          "sf": 1200,
          "unit_floor": 1
       },
             {
          "id": "f386a7ad-d6ea-6eb1-9b8f-56cd6104c445",
          "name": "3B Unit",
          "suite": "3B",
          "sf": 450,
          "unit_floor": 3
       },
             {
          "id": "b352dc84-8c76-6c27-daa4-56cd61e71aa2",
          "name": "3A Unit",
          "suite": "3A",
          "sf": 450,
          "unit_floor": 3
       },
             {
          "id": "8ec4325a-1271-560e-888b-56cd6120f5de",
          "name": "2B Unit",
          "suite": "2B",
          "sf": 450,
          "unit_floor": 2
       },
             {
          "id": "5a15fd5e-246a-be4b-fd5d-56cd619e9ee1",
          "name": "1B Unit",
          "suite": "1B",
          "sf": 450,
          "unit_floor": 1
       },
             {
          "id": "61a55092-5683-1088-2d6c-56c99c5d4873",
          "name": "2A Unit",
          "suite": "2A",
          "sf": 3000,
          "unit_floor": 2
       }
    ]
 }';
```

PHP:

```
    $jd = json_decode($json);
    $floors = array();
    foreach ($jd->records AS $key => $obj) {
        $f = $obj->unit_floor;
        $id = $obj->id;
        $name = $obj->name;
        $suite = $obj->suite;
        $sf = $obj->sf;
        $floors[$f][$suite]['name'] = $name;
        $floors[$f][$suite]['id'] = $id;
        $floors[$f][$suite]['sf'] = $sf;
    }
    //sort floors in desc order
    krsort($floors);
    foreach($floors as $id => $floor){
        ksort($floors[$id]);
    }
    print '<table>';
    foreach($floors as $floor => $suites){
        $sqf = 0;
        print '<tr>';
            print '<td>FLOOR: '.$floor.'</td>';
            foreach($suites AS $suite => $value){
                $sqf += $value['sf'];
                print '<td>Suite: '.$suite.'<br>SF: '.$value['sf'].'</td>';
            }
            print '<td>'.$sqf.'</td>';
        print '</tr>';
    }
    print '</table>';
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @mitkosoft, It is working as a separate file,. But the json i am getting by REST call is quite different and when I try to integrate this ccode with that json I'm getting an error like "array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array" , "Trying to get property of non-object " and so on,.

Comment: It was quite enough just to give us real JSON response, not a sample in order to give you right solution.

Comment: Here is my real problem,. Please have a look if you can solve this,. I have mentioned all URL's and valid credentials of mt test environment,. Please help me.     [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680962/consuming-json-data-in-php-table).

Comment: you have my anser there.

Answer (score 0):

this is other way to get the solution :

```
<?php
$json = '{
   "next_offset": -1,
   "records":    [
            {
         "id": "87dad127-a60e-15a3-148e-56c7675f11df",
         "name": "1A Unit",
         "suite": "1A",
         "sf": 1200,
         "unit_floor": 1
      },
            {
         "id": "f386a7ad-d6ea-6eb1-9b8f-56cd6104c445",
         "name": "3B Unit",
         "suite": "3B",
         "sf": 450,
         "unit_floor": 3
      },
            {
         "id": "b352dc84-8c76-6c27-daa4-56cd61e71aa2",
         "name": "3A Unit",
         "suite": "3A",
         "sf": 450,
         "unit_floor": 3
      },
            {
         "id": "8ec4325a-1271-560e-888b-56cd6120f5de",
         "name": "2B Unit",
         "suite": "2B",
         "sf": 450,
         "unit_floor": 2
      },
            {
         "id": "5a15fd5e-246a-be4b-fd5d-56cd619e9ee1",
         "name": "1B Unit",
         "suite": "1B",
         "sf": 450,
         "unit_floor": 1
      },
            {
         "id": "61a55092-5683-1088-2d6c-56c99c5d4873",
         "name": "2A Unit",
         "suite": "2A",
         "sf": 3000,
         "unit_floor": 2
      }
   ]
}';
```

function to parse data:

```
function createArray($unit_json){
    $max_unit_floor = 0;
    $subcells=array_map(function($n)use(&$max_unit_floor){
        if((int)$max_unit_floor < (int)$n->unit_floor){ $max_unit_floor = $n->unit_floor; }
        return preg_replace('/\d*/','',$n->suite);
    },$unit_json->records);
    $subcells = array_flip(array_flip($subcells));
    $cells = array();
    for($i = $max_unit_floor; $i > 0; $i--){
        $values = array();
        foreach($subcells as $v){
            $values[] = $i.$v;
        }
        $cells['floor_'.$i] = array('title'=>'Floor: '.$i,'values'=>$values,"total"=>0);
    }
    foreach ($unit_json->records as $unit_data){
        foreach ($cells as $key=>$value){
            for($i=0;$i<count($value['values']);$i++)
            if($value['values'][$i]==$unit_data->suite){
                $cells[$key][$value['values'][$i]] = array("sf"=>$unit_data->sf);
                $cells[$key]["total"] += (float)$unit_data->sf;
            }
        }
    }
    return $cells;
}
?>
```

html table:

```
<table class="stak-plan" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<?php 
$unit_json = json_decode($json);
$cells = createArray($unit_json);
foreach ($cells as $key=>$value) { 
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $value['title']?></td>
    <?php foreach($value['values'] as $k=>$cell){ ?>
        <td>Suite: <?php echo $cell?><br /> SF: <?php echo isset($cells[$key][$cell]['sf'])?$cells[$key][$cell]['sf']:''; ?></td>
    <?php }?>
    <td>sum: <?php echo $cells[$key]["total"]; ?></td>
</tr>  
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

response:

[image]

Comment: this works but it is not dymanic, as you have to define `$cells` manually

Comment: @CodeGodie, I fixed.

Comment: Thank you @miglio, It is working as a separate file,. But the json i am getting by REST call is quite different and when I try to integrate this ccode with that json I'm getting an error like "array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array" , "Trying to get property of non-object " "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" and so on,.

Comment: @hemanthkumar have you tried my answer? I was sure it would work.

Answer (score -1):

```
$json_string = "your json string like above";
//or you can $json_string = file_get_contents(url_return_your_json);
```

Then, you using `json_decode` for convert it to array

```
$your_array = json_decode($json_string,1);
```

Comment: @CodeGodie: Their was whole bunch of code like hundreds of lines. so I only added required code. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: @hemanthkumar No problem. Just make sure to include any areas that pertain to the problem so that we can approach the problem better.Regardless, like I said in my comment above, the problem is the way your JSON is formatted.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be your JSON format. You have *["trailing commas"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#example-4303)* that will prevent it from being decoded properly, and thus, getting empty results in your `foreach` loop. You have two options:

1. fix your JSON and remove the trailing commas

   ```
   {
       "next_offset": -1,
       "records":    [
               {
                  "id": "87dad127-a60e-15a3-148e-56c7675f11df",
                  "name": "1A Unit",
                  "suite": "1A",
                  "sf": 1200,
                  "unit_floor": 1, // <-- TRAILING COMMA
               }
        ]
   }
   ```
2. Use a function ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#91656)) that automatically removes these commas before you run your `json_decode`:

   ```
   function removeTrailingCommas($json)
   {
       $json = preg_replace('/,\s*([\]}])/m', '$1', $json);
       return $json;
   }

   $json = ''; // <-- your ogiginal JSON string

   $json = removeTrailingCommas($json);
   $unit_json = json_decode($json, 1);
   ```

Once you do that, you can then iterate in this manner to create your table:

```
$floors = array();
foreach ($unit_json['records'] as $record) {
    $floors[$record['unit_floor']][$record['suite']] = $record;
}
krsort($floors);
?>

<table class="stak-plan">
    <?php foreach ($floors as $floor_num => $floor_units) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Floor: <?= $floor_num ?></td>
            <?php
            ksort($floor_units);
            foreach ($floor_units as $unit) {
                ?>
                <td>
                    Suite : <?= $unit['suite'] ?><br>
                    SF : <?= $unit['sf'] ?>
                </td>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <td>
                <?php
                echo array_sum(array_map(function ($item) {
                    return $item['sf'];
                }, $floor_units));
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why the downvote? Maybe you can teach me something that I missed. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

To achieve this in PHP, load the file from somewhere using read() and then execute `json_decode()` in its contents, effectively creating an array, then use a `foreach` loop to iterate through each, using a template to display the values. **Also remember to pass the second argument as it creates an associative array instead of an object.**

```
$contents = //open file from fs or wherever you want to get it (curl, etc)
$array = json_decode($contents, 1); //argument for assoc array
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   // echo your table...
}
```

This is a rough idea of how to do it, but should get you on your way.

A more complete idea would be for example,

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($array as $key => $val): ?>
    <!-- your table arrangement in html -->
    <?= $key ?>
    <?php // do whatever you want here with the array... ?>
    <?= $value ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** I see your error, you're passing a key to a foreach loop but foreach loops take arrays as input, unless the array is inside the key. If so, I'd need to see where you're decoding and where you're dumping it.

Read more about json_decode here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

And here is an example of the argument in action:
https://eval.in/525451

Comment: I agree with this answer, however the OP (Original Poster) should provide some code that he/she has tried before any answers are provided.

Comment: They now updated their question and provided code. Nice.

Comment: UPDATE: Please, if downvoting, explain why. It's in the rules.